# JPA unidirectional OneToMany insert or update Parent with Children from JSON

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I want to write method which inserts parent and its children from given object when they do not exist in database or updates it when id is not null.

**For example:**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String property;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
    private Set<Child> children;
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Child{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String property;

    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Integer parentId;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Here is my code which I use for insert and it works fine:

```
@Transactional
public Parent save(Parent parent) {
    Set<Child> children = parent.getChildren();
    parent.setChildren(null);
    Parent mergedParent = entityManager.merge(parent);
    for(Child child : children) {
        child.setParentId(mergedParent.getId());
    }
    mergedParent.setChildren(children);
    return mergedParent;
}
```

parent is deserialized with Jackson from JSON:

```
{
  "property": "some val",
  "children": [
    {
      "property": "some val"
    },
    {
      "property": "some val"
    },
    {
      "property": "some val"
    }
  ]
}
```

Save method returns Parent object with id=1 and children with parentId=1 and ids from 1 to 3 - Parent and its Children are in database now.

After some changes outside the transaction I pass to save method previously returned Parent:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "property": "changed val",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "property": "some val",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "property": "some val",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "property": "changed val",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "property": "new child val"
    }
  ]
}
```

I receive exception (Parent entity exists in database, some children exist, some don't):

```
detached entity passed to persist: Child
```

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Have you tried checking for children without parent id and then setting it from the passed parent before saving ?

Comment: Your  CascadeType.All on the parent will take care of this for you.  Just save the parent the children will be deleted and reinserted accordingly.

Comment: If I use just `return entityManager.merge(parent)` there is error "Column 'PARENT_ID' cannot be null"